# how to map an array in an object map to another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

i have an object

```
{
    "parent_entity_id": 394,
    "display_name": "Test POI",
    "event_code_prefix": "TEST",
    "address": null,
    "logo_url": "https://storage.png",
    "is_active": true,
    "identifier": [
        {
            "model_id": 10,
            "entity_id": 575,
            "is_active": true,
            "valid_value": [
                {
                    "type": "MACID",
                    "value": "AC:23:3F:23:8D:A1"
                }
            ],
            "display_name": "Test BLE Beacon 1",
            "is_mandatory": true,
            "entity_type_key": "BTBACID"
        },
        {
            "model_id": null,
            "entity_id": 576,
            "is_active": true,
            "valid_value": [
                {
                    "type": "GEOFENCE_CIRCLE",
                    "value": {
                        "latitude": 24.155678,
                        "longitude": 54.425175,
                        "radius_in_meters": 500
                    }
                }
            ],
            "display_name": "Test tower gate 1",
            "is_mandatory": true,
            "entity_type_key": "GIS"
        }
    ]
}
```

I need to map the array valid values from the object to another array with condition.
if Ble the map to valid_value_BLE array and if GIS to valid_values_GIS

Comment: your question is not clear, please give more details

Comment: inside the object i have valid values. i want to put valid values to another array using a condition

Comment: When you are asking a question try to attach some code. It will be easier for others to answer.
Just run a Arr.forEach() and check for your condition and add them to a new array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
arr1=Obj.identifier.map(z => {
  if(z.entity_type_key=='GIS'){z['valid_value_GIS']=z.valid_value;
  }else{z['valid_value_BLE']=z.valid_value;}
  delete z.valid_value;  return z;
});
```

https://codepen.io/vkv88/pen/LYVZdwz?editors=0010